# can you add [Key] on a keyless entity?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am trying Entity Framework Core, so i stumbled upon a keyless table that i am trying to create a CRUD operation, since it is keyless, create, update and delete is impossible. So I thought, if I specify a key (there is a unique column that can be a primary key) this will fix the keyless problem in the EFCore. My question is, is this possible and if it is, how will i do this?

hope you guys can help me

PS altering the table is not allowed, so i need this workaround...

Comment: Have you tried adding [Key], or fluent code, to the unique column to see if it works?  You don't need to run any migrations to test this out.

Comment: Key**less** and Key are mutually exclusive. But yes, if you mark some unique required column as PK, EF Core will use it as if it is a real PK. It doesn't need to be a real PK in the database table if that's the question.

Comment: yes, i tried adding it, but on update, it still gives me the "unable to track an instance of type" error.

Comment: Make sure you removed `HasNoKey()` fluent call, because it takes precedence over the `[Key]` attribute. Or replace it with `HasKey(x => x.YourUniqueColumn)`

Comment: @IvanStoev and Neil thanks guys! i feel so dumb i only added [Key] in the model and not changing anything in the dbcontext. so what I did was change the hasnokey() in the dbcontext to haskey(e => 'the unique column') and it worked. Thanks again!!